# Disable Tiles Drag and Drop in DevExpress TileLayoutControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, tiles

How do I disable tiles drag and drop functionality in  DevExpress TileLayoutControl ?
I tried setting **DragScrolling** to **false** in xaml but it didn't work. I don't think that particular property is for disabling the drag and drop.

```
DragScrolling="False"
```

I searched everywhere but couldn't find what I was looking for. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If I remember right, there's a property to set `AllowItemMoving="False"`

Comment: Thanks Chris! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess I'll go ahead and place it as the answer then, the property you're apparently looking for is `AllowItemMoving="False"` which should do what you're looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm using DevExpress.XtraEditors.TileControl. In that not having "AllowItemMoving" property. what can I do?

Comment: Hi @Arya, unfortunately this answer is 5yrs old and I've not used this in several years myself. I wish I had an answer for you but I do not, perhaps try the documentation since I would have little insight to what all may have changed in so much time. However best of luck!